# Order saving error: Class Namespace\Module\Observer\OrderCancelled does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have an extension installed on my store which sends a notification when new orders are placed, canceled, hold, unhold etc.

When I am saving the order, I get an error saying

> Order saving error: Class Namespace\Module\Observer\OrderCancelled does not exist

But the Class exist as well in my project. I have run the following commands for my projects

```
1. php bin/magento setup:di:compile

2.php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

But that wouldn't solve my error.

Kindly help out with this error and how I could solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to change/missed/problem in the namespace. But not sure If you could put your code then it will be great for us to run and debug the error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the dependency injection related aspect.As file in project will not mean it will be included.Magento2 uses dependency injections as it does not want to load all modules( as was the case with Magento 1).

Hope this gives you an insight.Else post your complete module.